Cyclone 10lp FPGA not configuring through Flash chip (EPCQ64A ), but configures ok through JTAG (.sof)
We have developed a cyclone 10 Lp FPGA (10cl016Y) board, the Schematic is shown below

The FPGA chip configures good through JTAG using .sof file, but if the Flash chip is programmed using .jic file, the FPGA does not program.
I have measured the interface signals on oscilloscope, NStatus, Config_done, Flash_NCE, DATA0 and DCLK

Can you please suggest what could be the issue?
The configuration settings and .Jic file generation settings are shown in the images below



Swapping between DATA0 and DATA1 in the schematic sounds like a valid cause for problems.

@TurboJ you'd think, but the wiring of the flash is correct - bad naming conventions in one or other of the chips.

@Mohsin could you show the settings you've used in Quartus (Assignments->Device->Device and Pin Options->Configuration), along with the settings you used when converting the sof file to a jic

@TurboJ same kind of confusion is present in Cyclone 10LP evaluation kit from Intel, this isn't the issue here.

The schematic looks mostly correct. Really the MSEL[1] pin should be tied to VCCA (2.5V) not VCCIO (3.3V), and there should be a 25R resistor in series with the DATA1 pin of the flash memory. However neither of those should cause it to fail to configure, but ought to be fixed in a future revision.

@TomCarpenter, I have added images for Configuration settings and sof to jic file generation settings. Thank you
